# Python selenium for loop of getting values and creating namedtuples take too much time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, web-scraping

Following [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67866536/python-selenium-get-contents-of-a-webpage-added-by-javascript/), I have succeeded in some small parts of my task.

This is what I have put together so far:

```py
import os
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import itemgetter
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

song = namedtuple('song', 'artist title album duration artistlink songlink albumlink')

path = os.environ['APPDATA'] + '\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles'
path = (path + '\\' + os.listdir(path)[0]).replace('\\', '/')
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path)

Firefox = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
wait = WebDriverWait(Firefox, 30)

Firefox.get('https://music.163.com/#/playlist?id=158624364&userid=126762751')

iframe = Firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="g_iframe"]')
Firefox.switch_to.frame(iframe)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr')))

rows = Firefox.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr')

entries = []

for row in rows:
    column1 = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[2]/div/div/div/span/a')
    title = column1.text
    songlink = column1.get_attribute('href')
    duration = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[3]/span').text
    column3 = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[4]/div/span/a')
    artist = column3.text
    artistlink = column3.get_attribute('href')
    column4 = row.find_element_by_xpath('td[5]/div/a')
    album = column4.text
    albumlink = column4.get_attribute('href')
    entries.append(song(artist, title, album, duration, artistlink, songlink, albumlink))
```

The wait is a must, because the javascript takes some time to load all those entries, if the table is scraped too early there will only be 1000 songs at most.

I am concerned about the loop part, it takes more than three minutes to process just 2748 entries.

This line:

```
rows = Firefox.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr')
```

It gets the entire table pretty fast(under three seconds), but I don't know why using multiple `find_element_by_xpath()` and `get_attribute()` in a loop makes the code run slow.

Is calling these methods these many times in a short time period too taxing for the browser, or creating named tuple is inherently slow?

How can it be optimized?

Comment: `//table/tbody/tr` it just shows 6 entries to me. How is it fetching more than 2K items for you ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Like I wrote in the question body you need to install this https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/406054-%E7%BD%91%E6%98%93%E4%BA%91%E9%9F%B3%E4%B9%90%E6%98%BE%E7%A4%BA%E5%AE%8C%E6%95%B4%E6%AD%8C%E5%8D%95 in tampermonkey to lift the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about your code speed rather about it correctness.
Inside the `for` loop you are trying to search inside the specific row each time but I'm not sure you get what you intended.
When searching for a sub-element inside some parent node element you should start your XPath expression with `.` saying "from here", staring from this node element. Otherwise you will search with you relative XPath like `td[2]/div/div/div/span/a` relatively to the entire web page.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049983/selenium-webdriver-finding-an-element-in-a-sub-element) you can see this explanation.
Please try this and tell me if that made some changes:

```
for row in rows:
    column1 = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[2]/div/div/div/span/a')
    title = column1.text
    songlink = column1.get_attribute('href')
    duration = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[3]/span').text
    column3 = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[4]/div/span/a')
    artist = column3.text
    artistlink = column3.get_attribute('href')
    column4 = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[5]/div/a')
    album = column4.text
    albumlink = column4.get_attribute('href')
    entries.append(song(artist, title, album, duration, artistlink, songlink, albumlink))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't about performance. The more correct xpaths are appreciated, but I did get what I wanted with my xpaths.

Comment: OK, I just tried to help with what I know. As about the performance I currently have no idea, sorry